# Изменить размер шрифта в сайдбаре Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

Прочитал много решений, и все вроде понятно. но ничего не происходит. Понял что настройки сайдбара лежат в файле .sublime-theme, но найти его не могу.
Открываю browse package -> User создаю Default.sublime-themeи в него вношу след строки:

```
[
  {
    "class": "sidebar_label",
    "font.size": 8,
  },
]
```

Ничего не меняется 8(
думал изменить настройки в самом файле темы - но не могу найти где она лежит. Тема открывается и работает но где хранится не пойму. Ось - MacOs Siera. Подскажите плиз - а то очень не удобно -  гигантские буквы...

Comment: я так понял ты стороннюю тему установил? подскажи название?

Comment: Вы [**правильно**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaSublime/blob/3ea0cf2d6f97a488b0bff830ee3c2aaf819473dc/SashaSublime.sublime-theme#L198) поняли, где в файле нужно менять размер шрифта. Но делать это нужно не в заново созданном файле `Default.sublime-theme`, а в файле с расширением `.sublime-theme` Вашей активной темы. Если не знаете, как это сделать, ответьте на вопрос ув-мого @Air. Спасибо.

Comment: он, видать,уже разобрался))

Comment: @Air, ayu-mirage тема - не рпзобрался, проснулся тока

Comment: прикольная тема...  ты смотрел тут?  https://github.com/dempfi/ayu

Comment: на сколько я знаю, у меня просто так было и  я отказался от темы, если у самой темы не меняется данный шрифт, то его не поменяшь... но это не точно, 99% что я прав и так же 99% что не прав...  поковыряйся, в описании должно быть...

Comment: кстати, я установил себе тему, у меня нормальный шрифт

Comment: для моих глаз великоват шрифт сайдбара. Я не понимаю где эта тема валяется на компе! Не могу ее поиском даже найти! 8(

Comment: прости перепуталт ссылку   https://github.com/dempfi/ayu/blob/master/ayu-mirage.sublime-theme

Comment: Не могу на компе найти! В папке Packages - нету 8( но откуда то она ведь подгружается!

Comment: вот удалил ее, и установил заново - и все равно не найти где пакет храниться